# Firefox focus transition failure when focus starts in address bar

Tags: javascript, firefox, focus, onload, address-bar

When I attempt to set the focus to an input element when the page loads, it fails with Firefox in certain circumstances.  Here is the code:

```
:focus {
    outline: 3px solid #ff0000;
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    function setFocus() {
        document.getElementById('input-id').focus();
        document.getElementById('input-id').select();
        console.log(document.activeElement);
    }
</script>

<body onload="setFocus()">
    <div><input id="input-id" type="text" value="Waiting for focus..." onfocus="console.log('Received focus!')" /></div>
</body>
```

Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/johnericsutton/p6VhQ/. The idea is simply that when the page loads, the input element gets the focus (and the text gets selected).

It works in Firefox in these circumstances:

- put the cursor in the URL bar and press Enter;
- put the cursor in the input text and press Enter, or press the Reload button, or press Ctrl-R (on Windows and Linux, Cmd-R on Mac).

But it **doesn't** work in Firefox if you put the cursor in the URL bar and press the Reload button, or press Ctrl-R (on Windows and Linux, Cmd-R on Mac).  You can see from the console.log that the DOM believes that the activeElement **is** the input but this is NOT true in 2 senses:

- the CSS input selector is not activated;
- the input element has not received a focus event.

So the DOM is now in a confused state (which is causing serious problems in my application!) just because the user clicks in the URL bar and presses Reload rather than NOT clicking in the URL bar and pressing Reload or clicking in the URL bar and pressing Enter. What a mess!

By Firefox, I mean:

- FF15 on Linux and Mac;
- FF10 on Windows and Linux;
- FF9 on Windows.

It works fine on every version of Chrome and Safari that I have tried.

The only "solution" I have is to introduce an alert() before the .focus().  Not very satisfactory!  What shall I put in the alert? "Firefox bug workaround, please press OK!".

Any better ideas gratefully received :)

Answer (score -1):

Initalizing with a window.focus(); seems to push the focus out of the address bar.